# A question involving weak convergence in $\sigma(L^1, L^\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

Exercise 4.15 from H. Brezis - "Functional analysis..."

Let *I* = (0, 1) and $f_n = n e^{-n x}$ a sequence of functions. Show that 
$$ f_n \;\; \text{does not converge weakly to} \;\; 0 \;\; \text{in} \;\; \sigma (L^1, L^\infty). $$

In the book, at Solutions, we have the following:

Note that $\int f_n \varphi \to 0, \;\; \forall \varphi \in C_c(I)$.
Suppose, by contradiction, that $f_{n_k} \rightharpoonup f$ weakly $\sigma(L^1, L^\infty)$. It follows that  $$\int f \varphi = 0 \;\; \forall \varphi \in C_c(I).$$

Why $\int f \varphi = 0 \;\; \forall \varphi \in C_c(I)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to plug in the definitions and see what happens. If that does not help you, please clarify what exactly is unclear.

Comment: Unclear is why $f_{n_k} \rightharpoonup f$ implies that $\int f \varphi = 0 \;\; \forall \varphi \in C_c(I)$.

Comment: $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ means $\int f_n \cdot g \to \int f \cdot g$ for all $g \in L^\infty$. Each $\varphi \in C_c$ is also in $L^\infty$. Furthermore, $\int f_n \varphi \to 0$ for those $\varphi$ by assumption.